# HTML Javascript toggle visibility of 'select' ie dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a dropdown and label and surrounded them within a div, however, when i get the div in the following function, it doesnt hide/unhide the label and dropdown??

```
function ToggleDiv(DivID)
{
    if (document.getElementById(DivID).style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementById(DivID).style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(DivID).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

i've set the default visibility to hidden in the css, as i want the elements to be hidden and then revealled when a checkbox is clicked. Is this the problem? Is the css always making the elements hidden??

```
#unis
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

<div class='row'>
    <label id='Recruitmentlbl' for='Recruitment'>Recruitment?:</label>
    <input id='Recruitment' name='Recruitment' class='formcbx' type='checkbox' onclick=ToggleDiv("unis")<br />
</div>

<div class='row'>
    <div id = "unis">
    <label id='Universitylbl' for='University'>University institution:</label>
    <select name="uni">
        <option value="uni1">uni1</option>
        <option value="uni2">uni2</option>
        <option value="uni3">uni3</option>
        <option value="uni4">uni4</option>
        <option value="uni5">uni5</option>
    </select><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

but its not working?

Comment: Tom - FYI, you haven't "accepted" any answers give to your previous questions. You'll find that you'll get more help if you take the time to click the checkmark next to an answer that you found helpful. You can review your previous questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/359309/tom Just thought I'd let you know in case you weren't sure how it works. :o)

Comment: thanks, usually i copy and paste my code over, make an edit mistake and then the 'answer' is because of my edit- not the actual systematic problem- after 5 mins it never gets looked at again or 'answered'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JS can't really read the style.display that's set in the CSS. So when you test against "none" the actual value that could be returned might be `"none"` or `""` (no string at all.)

It's annoying, but test against the positive like this:

```
function ToggleDiv(DivID)
{
    if (document.getElementById(DivID).style.display != "block")
    {
        document.getElementById(DivID).style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(DivID).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Also, `visibility` and `display` are not the same thing. `Visibility` sets whether an object can be seen and `display` sets whether it has "layout". A div that has `display:none;` takes up no space on the page, but a div that has `visibility:hidden;` does. **So even if the code does toggle the `display` value, you also need to toggle the `visibility` value too.**

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save yourself from some typing (it's also faster):

```
function ToggleDiv(DivID) {
    var style = document.getElementById(DivID).style;
    style.display = (style.display != "none") ? "none" : "block";
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<p onclick="ToggleDiv('box')">toggle box</p>
<div id="box" style="display:none"></div>
```

About the visibility vs display issue. The difference is simple if you view it from the user's perspective.

- `display: none` looks like the element has been **removed**
- `visibility:hidden` looks like the element has been **hidden**

You can see a demo here: **[visibility vs display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)**

The main point is that the two is **not interchangeable**: setting one won't affect the other.

Comment: Yours won't work on all browsers because in some if the `display` hasn't been explicitly set with JS, it isn't readable with it.

Always look for the negative of "block."

Comment: which browser? I've tested `IE 5.5+, FF 3+, Chrome 5`. As a sidenote Prototype.js does the same thing, so can't be bad... :)